# what data type to use for user created object in a ruby create file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I built a simple blog following a tutorial. But then I wanted to try something a little bigger. So i wanted to make a blog with comments and users. Which means now my post need a user and an array of comments. My comments need to belong to a post, and my user has many posts and comments. So the question is in my create files how do i handle that.  I was just using string, text and integer. But what are they for arrays and user created models? Here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/3420711) on gist to see the code Also if there is anything that I am not doing that looks like a potential pit fall please let me know. Secondly, previously when i added a new variable to a model I found if i wanted to update the schema I had to rake db:rollback and then migrate again. Because just trying to migrate over the top did not update my schema. Is there a better way to do that?

thanks.

Comment: How are you determining that the schema has not changed? Through schema.rb, or through the Rails Console? If you're checking through the Rails Console, you need to restart the console after running migrations. You should be able to generate migrations on top of your old migrations regardless and see them change your database.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what tutorial you are following, but the best blog app tutorial is found in [the official docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

After reading through that you'll see that you are missing the main concept of model objects.

You will have three models: User, Post, Comment.

Models would look like this:

User

```
has_many :posts
has_many :comments
```

Post

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
```

Comment

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

In your migrations you will simple use an integer to define the belongs_to relationship.

In the Post migration: (this will vary depending on how you do your migrations, but concept is the same)

```
t.integer :user_id
```

For Comment:

```
t.integer :user_id
t.integer :post_id
```

Read through the guides and you will be fine.

Comment: Interesting, that clears up a lot. You left out that the has_many from  the migrations. That would mean that to find all the comments attached to the user I would have to do a look up of the user id in the database and find all the matching comments? I come from a C++ background, and now do ios and web, but all front end. So this Ruby and database stuff is a trip.

Comment: Read the guide I linked to and you'll get it. All you really have to do is user.comments and it will fetch the comments for that user.

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot. You don't do anything for the has_many in the migrations. The model already knows what to do. You just need the migration for the belongs_to.

Answer (score 0):

`Post` should `belong_to :user` rather than `has_one :user`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a bit of research on database schema design, but basically you need to add foreign keys to your tables and setup relationships between them.

For example, your comments table will need a `user_id` integer.  This will allow a particular comment to "point at" a user, so your application knows who wrote the comment.

Then in your User model, you should add the following:

```
has_many :comments
```

And in your Comment model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

The same basic idea can be applied to posts.